# Display divs side by side in mpdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am trying to display these two divs side by side in mpdf, but it is not working.

```html
<p>
    <div style="width:10px; float:left;">
        Standard:
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; float:left;">
        3
    </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your left div has 10px width, make it wider

```html
<p>
    <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
        Standard:
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; float:left;">
        3
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: I first tried it with 150px and it wasn't working, so I changed it to 10px to check. But when I increased it 70px it started working! Thanks.