# PHP mPDF: display divs side by side

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I want to display two `divs` in each row in my PDF, this is my code:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="height:auto; display:grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto;">');

foreach($images as $image){

    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div><img src="../'.$image.'" height="300" style="margin:5px;"></div>');

}

$mpdf->WriteHTML('</div>');
```

But the divs are stacking one over the other in my PDF file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onPTC.png)

When I try the same code in any html editor, the code works. Is this an issue with `mPDF` library? Doesn't it support `grid layout`?

**EDIT #1**: I've also tried this solution;

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div>');
$float = 0;
foreach($images as $image){
    if($float == 0){
        $float = 1;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="float:left;"><img src="../'.$image.'" height="300"></div>');
    }
    else{
        $float = 0;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="float:right;"><img src="../'.$image.'" height="300"></div>');
    }
}
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</div>');
```

The output is still the same, the divs are stacked one above the other

Comment: [from the docs](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) it seems there's no support for `display: grid`

Comment: Is there any other way to display the `divs` side by side? I want to display only two `divs` per row

Comment: you should be able to use `float` for that, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166459/display-divs-side-by-side-in-mpdf)

Comment: Yes I just tried the exact solution mentioned in the post, it doesn't work

Comment: try following their [official docs](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html), in the link they explain exactly your use case

Comment: Tried from there too, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Generate your HTML code beforehand and pass it to WriteHTML as a single "meaningful" chunk - there are position calculations done during the call itself
- Set width of your floated elements to be <50% of the parent so that breaking does not occur.
- Of course remember to clear lines of your floats where necessary.

This works:

```
$images = array_fill(0, 8, true);
$html = '';

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        $html .= '<div style="width: 45%; float: ' . ($key % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right') .  ';"><img src="https://placehold.co/300x200" height="300"></div>';
        if ($key > 0 && $key % 2 === 1) {
            $html .= '<div style="clear: both;"></div>';
        }
}

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```